# Looking to add a sequence number to an event based on the time of the event

Tags: sql

I am looking for an  SQL query that can help me add a sequence number based on the time of the event . The highlighted column in the table below is what I am looking to add into my result

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please put the entire question into the question... do not use images. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular... I would also recommend you take the [tour]

Comment: `row_number() over (partition by event_id order by occurance_time)` would work

Comment: @Alexey - how do you know it's `sql-server`?  `sql` tag is for the language, not the DBMS platform... it could be anything, and the image doesn't give any clues

Comment: @freefaller it's an ANSI SQL Standard Syntax

Comment: @Alexey - ah, fair enough, I thought it was SQL-server specific... neck wound back in

Answer (score 1):

Use the function row_number() to add a sequence number based on the event id and order by occurence time.

Reference: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/

```
SELECT 
   Event_ID, 
   Occurance_Time,  
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY Event_ID
      ORDER BY Occurance_Time
   ) Order_Sequence
FROM 
   dbo.sample_table
ORDER BY 
   Event_ID,
   Occurance_Time;
```